# Black border appears in all objects in a specific layer in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, shapes, stroke

I can't figure out why every time i use the shape tool to create something a black border appears around it. My stroke is off but it appears no matter what the black border appears when I use the shape tool.

[image]

It seems to only happen in the specific layer I am in, but not when I create a new one, so I'm guessing it has something to do with that.

How do I get rid of the border (from the pink rectangle in picture, for example)?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that you may have applied some graphic styles/effects to the layer. To fix it, try the following:

1. Select the problematic layer in the layers panel by targeting it.

[image]

2. Open the Appearance panel (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>) and remove any strokes, fills, or effects in there. The panel should look like this.

[image]